# Using hyphen in controller name in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, url-routing

Is it possible to use hyphen in controller name in cakephp instead of "_" ..
i tried

```
Router::connect('/best-practices', array('controller' => '/best_practices'));
```

but it didnt work ..

Answer (score 3):

That's because the routing is looking for a controller named `/best_practices`, which doesn't exist.

Try with no leading slash on the controller.

```
Router::connect('/best-practices', array('controller' => 'best_practices'))
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can use - (hyphen) in controller name as it will give you syntax Error.
But if you want to use hyphen in URL Then you can do something like this:

Create a controller with _ i.e. best_practices

And use routing for this for that open your  **/app/Config/routes.php** add

Router::connect('/best-practices/*', array('controller' => 'best_practices', 'action' => 'index'));